# How do you setup Paperclip to default to clipping rather than resizing images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I know this should be simple however I'm having a bit of a brain block.

I'm using paperclip for uploading profile images however it's currently resizing and distorting them.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :profile_image, 
                     styles: { square_50: "50x50" }
  ...
end
```

What I actually want it to do is to clip the images into the correct ratio then resize them to the desired size.

i.e. If my containing box is 200x200px and a 400x500px profile image is uploaded then I want it to  have 50px cropped off the top and bottom (to make it 400x400px) and for it then to be resized to 200px x 200px.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  `:square => '200x200#'` -- that should give you the square image you're looking for.